# Sudo As Other User and Brasero

Tags: sudo, brasero

I'm protecting application spaces by creating a new account for each application instance launched.  I create a disabled-non-admin account (no passwd set).  Then, I do this:

```
xhost local:braseroInstance_01
gksudo -u braseroInstance_01 /usr/bin/brasero
```

Brasero fires up!  But, can't see the blank dvd.  What is going on?

Brasero Message: Please replace the disk with a supported CD or DVD.
Gnome-Baker:  Cannot see the blank DVD either.

Comment: you paranoid ;)

Comment: The user should be in the `cdrom` group

Comment: I tried with Brasero.  No go.  I also realized that the iso permissions 700 root only. Set reading to others, 755, still nothing.  Add Gnomebaker to cdrom group, burned successfully.  Removed Gnomebaker, won't burn.  That's the anser for Gnomebaker, but Brasero is still in question.

Comment: @enzotib, if your comment was answer, which it really should be, because it covers atleast Gnomebaker, I could vote on it and give some acceptance to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the user to the `cdrom` group.

This can be done from command line with the following command

```
sudo gpasswd -a username cdrom
```

Take into account that for this command to take effect, the simplest thing is to logout and login again.